# How to resolve HandleMethod in spring mvc controller by request path(e.g./account/1)?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

A spring mvc rest project, there are below restful interfaces

```
/account/{id:\d+} GET #query account info
/account/{id:\d+} PATCH #update account balance
/transferlog POST #add transfer log
```

In addition, there is a interface supporting batch operations, like below

```
POST /trans/batch HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
"requests": [
    {
        "method": "GET", 
        "path": "/account/2"
    }, 
    {
        "method": "GET", 
        "path": "/account/1"
    }, 
    {
        "method": "PATCH", 
        "path": "/account/1?amount=10"
    }, 
  {
        "method": "POST", 
        "path": "/transferlog", 
        "body": {
            "fromId": 2, 
            "toId": 1, 
            "amount": 10
        }
    },
   {
        "method": "PATCH", 
        "path": "/account/2?amount=-10"
    }

]
}
```

This is mocking a transfer business logic, and I'd like to in batch method to resolve target method and bean by above method and path info. For example

Bootstrap log

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/account/{id:\d+}]}" onto public com.example.domain.Account com.example.web.TansactionalDemoController.getAccount(int)

s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/account/{id:\d+}],methods=[PATCH]}" onto public com.example.domain.Account com.example.web.TansactionalDemoController.updateBalance(int,int)
```

That is

```
GET /account/1 --> TansactionalDemoController.getAccount(int)

PATCH /account/1?amount=10 --> TansactionalDemoController.updateBalance(int,int)
```

Then in batch method invoking these target method by reflection, by this I could guarantee these operations in a transactional(@Transactional). If I use HttpClient to invoke these request, it is very difficult to guarantee transaction.

Now my question is how to get target method and bean(TansactionalDemoController.updateBalance(int,int)) only by above method and path parameters and meantime also could resolve those path vaiable?

```
 {
        "method": "PATCH", 
        "path": "/account/2?amount=-10"
    }
```